# What's the best driver for NVIDIA GeForce GT 230 M

Tags: drivers, nvidia, graphics

I've installed the new Version of Ubuntu 13.04. It works great but i think the system can run more faster with the right driver of my hardware. I actually use the NVIDIA GeForce GT 230 M.

I'm sorry, but my english is as bad as my linux knowledge ;-)

I'm not sure, which driver i should take. Currently the X.org Driver is selected but is this the best i can take?

Comment: Please see here: http://askubuntu.com/questions/61396/how-to-install-a-video-card-nvidia-ati-or-intel but yes, as thefourtheye mentioned, the last one for that video card is the 313 one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
sudo apt-get install nvidia-313-updates
```

is the latest stable nvidia driver

Answer (score 0):

I have a 260GTX and am currently running 313 with very nice results.

Installed it through synaptics in a few minutes.  Was easy install and get the performance and features you normally expect from nvidia products.